# Prove or disprove that $f\left(x\right)\leq 1,$ which is a continuous function so that $\int_0^x tf\left(2x-t\right){\rm d}t=\frac{\tan^{-1}x^2}{2}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, continuity, substitution, integral-inequality

> Prove or disprove that $f\left ( x \right )\leq 1,$ where $f$ is a continuous function so that
> $$\int_{0}^{x}tf\left ( 2x- t \right ){\rm d}t= \frac{\tan^{-1}x^{2}}{2}$$
> Source: AoPS/@Ji123_ https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/q1h144652p819322

I *edited* the original problem a little bit, my friend@twelve_sakuya also has a completed disproof *in* case $f\left ( x \right )< 1,$ we substitute
$$t\mapsto 2x- t\Rightarrow\int_{0}^{x}tf\left ( 2x- t \right ){\rm d}t\equiv\int_{x}^{2x}\left ( 2x- t \right )f\left ( t \right ){\rm d}t$$
$$\frac{{\rm d}}{{\rm d}x}\int_{x}^{2x}\left ( 2x- t \right )f\left ( t \right ){\rm d}t= \frac{{\rm d}}{{\rm d}x}\left ( 2x\int_{x}^{2x}f\left ( t \right ){\rm d}t- \int_{x}^{2x}tf\left ( t \right ){\rm d}t \right )= 2\int_{x}^{2x}f\left ( t \right ){\rm d}t- xf\left ( x \right )$$
On the other hand
$$\frac{{\rm d}}{{\rm d}x}\frac{\tan^{-1}x^{2}}{2}= \frac{x}{x^{4}+ 1}\quad\therefore 2\int_{x}^{2x}f\left ( t \right ){\rm d}t- xf\left ( x \right )= \frac{x}{x^{4}+ 1}$$
When $x> 0,$ we have
$$f\left ( x \right )= \frac{2}{x}\int_{x}^{2x}f\left ( t \right ){\rm d}t- \frac{1}{x^{4}+ 1}= 2f\left ( c \right )- \frac{1}{x^{4}+ 1}\quad\left ( x< \exists c< 2x \right )$$
(According to Mean-value theorem), if $x\rightarrow +0\Rightarrow c\rightarrow +0\Rightarrow f\left ( 0 \right )= 2f\left ( 0 \right )- 1\quad\left ( x\rightarrow +0 \right ),$ so $f\left ( 0 \right )= 1,$ we have contractdiction.

Comment: There is no need for those superfluous `\left` and `\right` when you only enclose "normal" $x$.  They are there for things like displayed fractions or limits that are larger than what typical parenthesis/bracket/... provide for.

Comment: @user10354138, sorry for my perfectionism.

Comment: I never use ``\dfrac`` and ``\limits`` in the title, trust me.

Comment: It is not perfectionism to put `\left` and `\right` needlessly when it [doesn't even do it correctly](//tex.stackexchange.com/a/2610).

Comment: The series expansion of $f(x)$ is $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{\left(-1\right)^{k}\left(4k+1\right)}{-3+2^{4k+2}-4k}x^{4k}$.

Comment: @VarunVejalla, thanks for your valuable comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Leibnitz integral rule:

$xf(x) = \dfrac{x}{x^4+1}$

Let $x \in \mathbb{R} - \{ 0\}.$ Now we can divide the above expression by $x$ as $x\ne0.$

$f(x) = \dfrac{1}{x^4+1}$ which is clearly less than one as denominator is always greater than numerator. Now lets include zero into the domain...

Substituting zero into the original equation we have:

$0f(0) = \dfrac{0}{0^4+1} =0 \implies f(0) \in \mathbb{R}$. But its given $f(x)$ is continuous. Hence LHL must equal RHL.  $\lim_{x \to 0} \dfrac{1}{x^4+1} = 1$. Hence f(0) must equal 1.

Now we have: $f(x) \leq 1 \forall x \in \mathbb{R}$